# LeakCanary не находит утечку

Tags: android

Создал тестовое приложение, добавил зависимости, как на оф. сайте. Создал искусственную утечку, все работает, приходит уведомление, но когда переношу код в релизный проект, в логах вижу, что LeakCanary только наблюдает и не замечает утечку, никаких уведомлений нет. Подскажите с чем это может быть связано.

Зависимость:

```
debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.0-alpha-2'
```

Код активности:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    MyAsyncTask().execute(this)
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()

    LeakSentry.refWatcher.watch(this)
}

inner class MyAsyncTask :
    AsyncTask<Context, String, String>() {

    //private var context: Context? = null

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Context?): String {

        Thread.sleep(10000)

        return "result"
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Решено! Если кому интересно, то проблема была в gradle файле.
В BuildTypes было

```
debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        debuggable true
}
```

а надо

```
debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
}
```